# C# - ¿Cómo obtener los folders del calendario de otra cuenta diferente a la mía?

Tags: c#, webservice, calendar, outlook

Estoy tratando de encontrar la forma de poder traerme los folders de calendario de otra cuenta diferente a la mía...

Tengo esto...

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
foreach (Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder in folder.Folders)
{
    GetFolders(subFolder);
}
```

*GetFolders() es un método que recorre los folders*

Y con eso me traigo los calendario de mi cuenta vinculada a la app de escritorio de outlook... lo que quiero es que en vez de que se traiga mis calendarios se traiga los de otra cuenta

.
**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**
El código anterior funciona de forma remota, es decir que siempre voy a estar trabajando con la app de escritorio de outlook (lo acabo de leer jeje)
Bueno, el punto es que para poder traerme esos calendarios que ocupo de otra cuenta, necesito usar WebServices, en específico necesito usar EWS... el problema aquí es que no se como hacerle para usar ese webservice y traerme los calendarios de la otra cuenta...
*¿Alguna idea?*

Comment: Quieres trabajar con el Outlook específicamente? O deseas acceder a las carpetas de un servidor de correo en específico? Son cosas diferentes. Ahora, cuando dices que quieres acceder a carpetas de otro usuario, te refieres a otro usuario del servidor o a otro usuario de la máquina en donde estas accediendo al Outlook?

Comment: Quiero trabajarlo web... no quiero que mi app se conecte a la app de escritorio de Outlook.
Deseo acceder a los *calendarios* de otra cuenta diferente a la mía, en específico a una cuenta de office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No evalauste hacer uso de metodo `Logon()` para autenticarte con otro usuario.

[How to: Get and Log On to an Instance of Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097.aspx)

[How can I open new mail in outlook with different user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075769/how-can-i-open-new-mail-in-outlook-with-different-user)

Si no realizas esto entonces la instancia de Application accedera con als credencales por defecto definidas para el usuario que este autenticado

Comment: Ya lo implementé, ¿pero en que momento le paso las credenciales para que me traiga los calendarios de la otra cuenta?

Porque, ¿como va a saber ese método que quiero acceder a otra cuenta?

Comment: Acabo de ver que para eso que quiero se ocupa EWS, ¿sabes como hacerlo usando ese webservice?